# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'qr.<locals>.confirm' was never awaited

Tags: python, flask, async-await, jinja2

I'm writing a webapp in Flask. Within one of my routes, I have a function that listens to an API and waits for a payment to be registered. The function is called `confirm()`. I pass it in the `render_template` as `confirm=confirm` and I call it on the page using Jinja2: `{{ confirm(cost) }}`

I've realised that the function needs to be called asynchronously because otherwise the page doesn't load until the payment is made. However, I'm getting the titular error that the function needs to be awaited. Having read around, I've tried changing the route to `async def qr()` but Flask won't load it so I'm not sure how `await` should be used in this case.

```
async def confirm(cost):
        json = { "action": "account_history", "account": app.config['NANO'], "count": 5, "raw": False, "reverse": False }
        now = datetime.now()
        delta = timedelta(seconds=60)
        while datetime.now() < now+delta:
            test = requests.post("https://nanoverse.io/api/node",json=json).json()
            for item in test["history"]:
                if item["amount"] == cost:
                    flash("Payment Received!")
                    break
            else:
                continue
            break
```

Comment: I can't imagine how Python's async/await could solve that problem. (If somebody posts an answer showing how to await the coroutine, I will be very happy to learn from it.) I would render a webpage with an AJAX script (JS, JQuery, ...) responsible for the payment confirmation. That script might invoke the (regular, not async) `confirm()` function on the same server, so you can do the main work in Python.

Answer (score 3):

To be able to use `Awaitable` objects within jinja2 templates, the `environment` must be created with the `enable_async` option.
Ref: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/#async-support

To do this from flask you need to set it via `jinja_options` before running the app. Like this:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.jinja_options['enable_async'] = True
```

Now there's only one issue remaining. Based on the `AsyncSupport` documentation of jinja2:

> `asyncio.get_event_loop()` must return an event loop.
> Since flask creates a new Thread for each request there will be no evet_loop for jinja. So something like this must be done to get it working:

```py
@app.route('/')
def example():
    # ...
    asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())
    
    return render_template('index.html', confirm=confirm)
```

Be cautious with how you'd provide the event loop. I don't think this a production-ready approach. This is just a proof of concept to demonstrate how it should work. I think the "best practices to provide event_loop for flask threads" is a whole another question.

Comment: This is amazing because it gives me hope that it's possible. However, at the moment I'm encountering a few problems. First, does the function definition have to be prefixed like: 'async def confirm(cost):' ? Second, I'm getting the following error: RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-3'.

Comment: Well, to answer the second question first, the last part of my answer is supposed to solve this error. did you put this line in your handler function: `asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())`.
And about the `async` keyword, your question was based on this :)) If you want it to be asynchronous, then it's required to write the `async` keyword.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm still getting that error. Each time I refresh, the Thread increases by 7, so Thread-3, Thread-10, Thread-17, etc.

Comment: @JackPutter That's weird. This is a working snippet I wrote. could please test this as well? https://gist.github.com/mehdy/0309db45a9cb2fe0d99f32808a678f3b

Comment: It's better but now the page doesn't load until the coroutine has finished.

Comment: @JackPutter That's right. If you want the page to be loaded partially and load the other stuff asynchronously you should return a minimal js application to render the page and it tries to load other resources from your APIs. something like reactJS for example.